# how to check if a $_FILE is set in php?

Tags: php, file

I've created a form with 3 `<input type="file"/>`

I see that I get an array with `array(name=>"")`.

So I check `if ($_FILE["myfilename"]["name"]=="")` instead.

This works but it seems rather unusual to me.

I was wondering if there was a better way to check if a file input is set or not?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is: [`is_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/is_uploaded_file). When dealing with uploaded files, you should always use it (and its cousin [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/move_uploaded_file)) for security reasons.

Comment: I'm confused about the usefulness of `is_uploaded_file`. In the PHP source there seems to exist a secondary hash. But the values are always identical to the ones in `$_FILES[*]['tmp_name']`. And it checks for nothing else. Not sure how one could inject something into $_FILES during script runtime. (`Is_uploaded_file` would be redundant if you use `move_uploaded_file`, because it contains the copy&pasted exactly same test anyway.)

Comment: @mario there used to be a vulnerability in PHP 4 that I actually managed to break into a friend's phpBB with once: It was possible to inject local file paths (think `../config.php`) into `tmp_name`, leading that file to be copied into the public `uploads/` directory or wherever. `is_uploaded_file()` was introduced in response to that. Whether the vulnerability still exists if you don't use `is_uploaded_file()`, I don't know, I've never checked since

Comment: Interesting. So, it's all your fault then? Downvoted for hacking.. ;}

Comment: I'm still quite new with the file uploading concept.
So, if I get this right, when I press the upload button on my form, the server is already uploading the file hence is_uploaded_file.

if is_uploaded_file($_FILES["inputFieldName"]){
 move_uploaded_file($_FILE["inputFieldName"],$destinationFolder)
}

Is that correct?

Comment: @ndefontenay the latter part is correct; the former isn't: The upload starts when you click the upload button. The PHP script comes to life *after* all files have been completely uploaded. `is_uploaded_file()` is just a fancy (and, as said above, security enhanced) way of checking the `FILES` array

Comment: @pekka ok, so is_uploaded_file() checks that all files has been uploaded therefore I can't single out on one of them to check if it's a valid file which means I'm better off using the command mentioned by @Ciaran McNulty $_FILE['myfilename']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK.

Comment: @ndefontenay no, you can (and should) use `is_uploaded_file()` without limitations. Check out the example in the manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php that should show the correct usage

Comment: @pekka Ok.

Got some exemple. Will try out a few things. Thanks

Comment: Interesting.. I was not aware of this function (in 2022 lol). Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [**empty**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) to check if a variable is blank or not but Pekka's solution is best in this way

```
if (empty($_FILES["myfilename"]["name"]))
```

If you are checking that if a variable is set you can use [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function

Answer (score 4):

The best way, assuming you're using a recent PHP (4.2+), is to check that:

```
$_FILE['myfilename']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK
```

If this is true the upload worked, you can see the list of other possible values [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)

Comment: you should use the strict equality comparison `===`. If you should ever make a type on the ERR_OK constant, the regular comparison will give a false "ok".

Comment: Very good point Marc, especially as the value of it is (int)0.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
if($_FILES['myfilename']['size'] > 0 ) {

}
else{
       echo 'File is not uploaded . . .';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if($_FILES["uploadImg"]['name'][0] != ''){
    //echo 'file attached';
}else{
    //echo 'no file attached';
}
```

This works for me...